# Goods Receipts creation issue

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have a problem:

I create goods receipts using transaction MB1C, filling Document Date, Posting Date, Mov. type, Plant, Stor.Location ... Press New Item -> filling Material, quantity, stor. type, Batch, Storagin Bin and Manuf. Date ... 
Then I can display the created batch in MSC3N... If I open the tab Classification, and press Set Classification Status, the status = 'Incomplete'.

The steps described above I do also with Batch Input Session ... !the same steps .. But, when I open Classification Status, the status = 'Released'.

My question is why that's happening? I use the same values in both cases, nothing is different!!!

thanks..

Comment: You are not using the same environment conditions. You may have an EXIT what takes decisions based in T-Code, user, batch process... Did you checked any enhancements for that transaction?

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I've check each possible User Exit, but not result ... also the SY structure is the same for both cases (BI session and manual running of MB1C)

Comment: I assume enhancements and BAdIs have been checked too. Is the status change immediate or it could have been made by a job?
Any TRIGGER associated to this kind of object?
(I'm not used to this T-Code, and I must think generic about your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, there are many reasons why a batch input might behave differently from a manual input, so you should do several tests until you discover the reason.

**[>>> Please refer to this table (in SCN) which gives the possible reasons and solutions](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Why+batch+input+%28BDC%29+behaves+differently+from+manual+input).**

Note that this table is generic and is not limited to one transaction code (MB1C in your case).

PS: it's not clear what you exactly did: you are talking about running a batch input session and checking the "SY structure" (I guess you are talking about the return code SY-SUBRC), but a "session" means that it's a recording in transaction code SM35, but the only way to run it is by calling a "report", so you don't get SY-SUBRC. Therefore, I guess you are not running a session, but doing the batch input (not session) using the ABAP statement [CALL TRANSACTION USING (CTU)](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_transaction_using.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I will find the main divergence